# Google Appscript unable to invoke server side function using google.script.run function

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

My setup is as follow:

I have a bound appscript named `MainCode.gs` and `MainPage.html` in my google sheet. On top of that, I have a standalone Appscript Library with `LibraryCode.gs` and `LibraryPage.html`.

---

The `MainCode.gs` will show the `MainPage.html` as the custom sidebar. On the `MainPage.html`, there will be a button which is used to invoke the server side function `showDialog()` from the `LibraryCode.gs` when clicked. Please note that the library code script is imported as `myLibrary`

[image]

**MainCode.gs**

```
function showSideBar(){
   var widget= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("MainPage");
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(widget); 
   }

function Report(){
   myLibrary.showDialog();
   }
```

**MainPage.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
     <button type="button" onclick="LogIssue()" class="menu-item-button"> Log Issue </button>

     <script>
      function LogIssue(){
        google.script.run.Report();}
     </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

When `showDialog()` function is called, `LibraryCode.gs` will display a Modeless Dialog with a submit button. Pressing this submit button should invoke an alert with "Hello World!" text.

[image]

**LibraryCode.gs**

```
function showDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('LibraryPage');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(html, "Test");
}

function submit(){
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("HELLO WORLD!");
}
```

**LibraryPage.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
     <input type="button" class="menu-item-button" onclick="submitIssue()" value="Submit Issue" />

     <script>
       function submitIssue(){
       google.script.run.submit();}
     </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

My problem is when I click on the "Submit Issue" button, the `google.script.run.submit()` function does not do anything.Based on my code, it should invoke the `submit()` function and create alert with "Hello World!" text. What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the script needs a `submit` function in the main page:

```
function submit(){
  myLibrary.submit();
}
```

Please do note that the [Best practice is to avoid libraries in UI heavy scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#avoid_libraries_in_ui-heavy_scripts).

Comment: Thank you. That solved it. I was under the assumption that the `google.script.run` from the Library  `.html` will invoke the `.gs` code from the Library and not the main code. May be I need to take a look at the documentation more